# Kamon error with configuration 'requires-aspectj'

Tags: akka, aspectj, kamon

I'm adding `kamon`to my standalone *akka* application and i'm getting this error:

`com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'requires-aspectj'` error at `Kamon.start()`.

This is the relative content of *application.conf*.

```
{
...
  modules {
    kamon-akka {
      auto-start = no
    }
    kamon-statsd {
      auto-start = no
    }
    kamon-system-metric {
      auto-start = no
      requires-aspectj = no
      extension-id = "kamon.system.SystemMetrics"
    }
  }
}
```

`application.conf: 36: requires-aspectj has type STRING rather than OBJECT`

However, when I include the asked property

```
{
  modules {
    requires-aspectj = no
  ...
  }
}
```

I get this error: `application.conf: 36: requires-aspectj has type STRING rather than OBJECT`

If i remove `Kamon.start()` my application starts as usual

This is an extract of the my *build.sbt*:

```
lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(name := "kamon-akka")
  .settings(Seq(scalaVersion := "2.11.8"))
  .settings(libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    akka.Http,
    akka.slf4jApi,
    akka.akkaSlf4j,
    kamon.Core,
    kamon.Akka,
    kamon.LogReporter,
    kamon.SystemMetrics,
    aspectj.aspectjtools,
    aspectj.aspectjweaver,
    aspectj.aspectjrt
  ))
  .settings(aspectjSettings: _*)
```

PS:

- kamon = 0.6.7
- aspectj = 1.8.9
- sbt 0.13.13
- scala 2.12.3
- I'm also using this plugin `addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-aspectj" % "0.9.4")`

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your `application.conf` looks strange in that it doesn't appear to have a `kamon` namespace. It should look like the following (take note of the first line):

```scala
kamon {
  ...
  modules {
    kamon-akka {
      ...
    }
    kamon-statsd {
      ...
    }
    kamon-system-metrics {
      ...
    }
  } 
}
```

Second, since you're using the `sbt-aspectj` plugin, add the following to your `build.sbt` (source: http://kamon.io/documentation/get-started/):

```scala
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtAspectj._

// Bring the sbt-aspectj settings into this build
aspectjSettings

// Here we are effectively adding the `-javaagent` JVM startup
// option with the location of the AspectJ Weaver provided by
// the sbt-aspectj plugin.
javaOptions in run <++= AspectjKeys.weaverOptions in Aspectj

// We need to ensure that the JVM is forked for the
// AspectJ Weaver to kick in properly and do it's magic.
fork in run := true
```